# Segfault when derefing iterator

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm following the example [here](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-instruction-in-a-function). My complete code is

```
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/InstIterator.h"
using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  struct Hello2 : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification, replacement for typeid
    Hello2() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
      inst_iterator iter = inst_begin(F); // causes a segfault    
      return false;
    }
  };
}

char Hello2::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Hello2> Y("hello2", "Hello World Pass");
```

following the "HelloWorld" pass example explained [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html). When I followed the example exactly, it worked fine, but with the modified pass code above, I get the segfault when I run `opt`.
(I'm using the same "hello.c" file for input as in the "HelloWorld" pass example, compiling it with clang, running `make` and calling my library with `opt` just as in the example.)

What's causing my segfault, and is there any way to test for it/avoid it?

**EDIT**

I traced the segfault to line 61 of [InstIterator.h](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/InstIterator_8h_source.html): `BI = BB->begin();`. When my code reaches that point, `BBs` is non-NULL, but `BB=BBs->begin()` is NULL. Thus the dereference of `BB` results in a segfault. The question of *why* `BB` is NULL (and why the constructor doesn't check for that) remains.

Comment: Can you provide the IR you are running this pass? And what LLVM version are you using?

Comment: LLVM 3.5.1, using the `hello.bc` file generated by clang 3.5.0 following the directions in the link for the `HelloWord` pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved when my system did an automatic update and got a new version of several llvm-3.5 packages (today). Previously, `opt --version` returned

```
LLVM version 3.5

Optimized build.
Built Mar 23 2014 (21:41:30).
Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Host CPU: corei7
```

now it returns

```
LLVM version 3.5.0

Optimized build.
Built Jan 27 2015 (00:14:48).
Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Host CPU: corei7
```